# Best experiences to storing different types of data in an Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, data-structures

Good evening

I am currently developing a Java application. Now I want to enable the user to save an indefinite number of associated attachments for a object.

These attachments can be of the following types: string, xml file, binary files.

I use an Oracle db as the database. A different data type is actually recommended for each type:
String - VARCHAR
XML file - CLOB
Binary file - BLOB

What's the best way here? A general table, which among other things contain the 3 fields (varchar, clob, blob) and depending on the type are two fields then NULL or three separate tables?

Am looking forward to your answers

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about "wasted" space by having a single table with three different columns for each broad classification of `VARCHAR2`, `CLOB`, and `BLOB`.  Oracle won't use any (meaningful) amount of space doing this, and if you had 3 tables, that would only complicate things.  You have picked the appropriate data types for those types of file content.

I would also have an additional column, `FILE_TYPE VARCHAR2(10)` that could have the file type in it, for convenience.  And that column would be limited via a simple inline constraint to validate the `FILE_TYPE`:

```
create table user_files (
    file_name varchar2(4000) not null, 
    , file_type varchar2(8) not null check (file_type in ('VARCHAR2', 'CLOB', 'BLOB'))
    , text_data varchar2(4000)
    ,xml_data  clob
    , binary_data blob
   );
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. :) Alternatively, I could use a clob field as the smallest common denominator. A string as well as an XML file but also a base64 coded file would fit in there. Oracle seems to use a varchar internally as long as the content of the clob is below 4000 characters. I'm just not sure which of the two ways is better.

Comment: For text data, the VARCHAR2 can be better for searching for things, in general.  And if you had just one column for the  data, regardless of the type of data, either the application or user retrieving data wouldn't have to look at the results to decide if/how to decode it; unless you had my magic `file_type` column, but that too could be more work.